# Python: understanding read() in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I am watching an OpenCV tutorial and in one place he writes this code:

```
while True:
   success, img = cap.read() 
   cv2.imshow("Video", img)
   if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF ==ord('q')):
      break
```

I am confused about the second line. According to the voiceover, it stores the read image in `img` and also saves a boolean value to `success` recording whether we were able to read the image. That makes sense. I just don't know what the purpose of `success` is, but if I delete it, errors occur on line 3.

According to `imshow()` method it just takes in a String for the window name, and then the img (which we had above). So I am not sure why `success` is needed.

(There is no other code on the screen outside of the import statement)

Comment: If you don't want that variable you can use `_` like this `_ , img = cap.read()`

In python it is possible that method returns more than one value so we need to handle that while calling such methods. example: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-returns-multiple-values-how-to-return-a-tuple-list-dictionary/

Comment: Variable `success` has to be checked every time since it will  help you to raise an error if there's some problem reading the frame or so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `cap.read()` returns is a boolean (True/False) and image content. If you remove `success`, the `img` variable takes that boolean and image data as a tuple. This is why you get an error.

`.read()` in OpenCV returns 2 things, boolean and data. If there are not 2 variables, a tuple will be assigned to one variable. The boolean is mostly used for error catching. Assigning a tuple to 1 var with 2 data items can sometimes be useful, but in this instance, you should create 2 vars and split the data into 2 variables to make it easier.

If you do not want to assign the bool to a var, you can use `_` as the variable name.

Comment: no, if you only say `img = cap.read()`, img is now a **tuple**. `img` does not take that boolean. that boolean MUST NOT be ignored. it must be checked because that is how OpenCV indicates that the frame could actually be read. it is absolutely wrong to claim "If there are not 2 variables being assigned, the 1st item will be assigned"

Answer (score 1):

`cap.read()` returns a tuple, which contains a boolean success flag, and the video frame.

if the video has ended, the success flag is False. in that case, the frame is empty.

you MUST test that flag and end the loop.

the tutorial you watched failed to do so. it taught you wrong.

in addition, you must check if `cap.isOpened()` because opening the video file (or camera) could have failed, and you need to react to that.

here is the proper code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(...) # open a video file or camera
assert cap.isOpened(), "file/camera could not be opened!"
while True:
   (success, img) = cap.read() # cap.read() always returns a tuple of two things
   if not success: break # you absolutely must check this
   cv2.imshow("Video", img)
   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
      break
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to OpenCV document about videocapture read.
It returns the status and image being captured.  The "success" is not necessary,  but recommended.  It tells you whether you have successfully captured a image.  In your case,  if you get an error at third line, you can do img = cap.read()[1], then it should work.  However,  this is not recommended,  as it's possible that the return is none,  due to the failure of capturing any image.